# How can we define different variable group for different schedule trigger in Azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Different variable group for different schedule trigger in Azure devops

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you would like to use variable in different variable groups in different schedule triggered pipelines? What about go to UI->library->choose the specific variable group then choose pipeline permission and add the corresponding schedule pipelines.
[image]
Then add the variable group name in the schedule pipelines yml and you could output the value of variables in the group, for example if there is a variable named 'SomeNumber' in the variable group.

```
   variables:
    - group: MyVarGroup
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
       targetType: 'inline'
       script: Write-Host "$(SomeNumber)"
```

But if you mean to add variable into the schedule trigger syntax, you can't use pipeline variables when specifying schedules in yml. You could see the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-triggers) for more details.

If it is not what you want, please kindly specific your issue with the sample yaml, then I will try to do further investigation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... Actually I want to add Variables through UI. I have 2 sets of variables and want to add each variable group for each schedule trigger. Can you help me on this...